# Can a user transfer X and Y tokens to a smart contract in a single transaction/interaction with the smart contract?

Tags: delegatecall, transfer, erc-20-approve

I'm trying to develop a contract to which users would send certain amounts of tokens A and B to the smart contract. Easiest/obvious way to do it would be to do several transactions in this order:

1. User calls `approve` for tokenA for an amount of X where the smart contract is the spender
2. User calls `approve` for tokenB for an amount of Y where the smart contract is the spender
3. User then calls the smart contract which uses `transferFrom` the user to the smart contract for those amounts

This is however very cumbersome for the user, who has to sign and send 3 different transactions.

Is there a way where the user can call a single function in my smart contract, and the smart contract can transfer those funds from the user directly? I'm thinking something similar to what Uniswap v2 uses:

```
// bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));
(bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0xa9059cbb, to, value));
```

Although probably using `delegatecall()` would be more appropiate in this context.

Would this work or would the user still need to set an approval? Any ideas on how could I improve the user experience in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, and that is by design. A smart contract that just needs one call to approve all your erc20 to be transferred to someone else is obviously a huge security issue.

If you want to approve a token, you need to call the approve function of that token. No way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And why wouldn't it work to call `(bool success, bytes memory data) = token.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSelector(0xa9059cbb, to, value));` ? Wouldn't even be like if the EOA calling the smart contract function is also directly calling the `transfer()` function of the token directly (since we are using `delegatecall()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understood your second question. Could you explain? Also, could you mark my answer as valid if it helped you? Thanks

Comment: Because of the context, if we use `delegatecall()` it would be as if the EOA account is calling transfer themselves even if there is a smart contract in the middle calling the `transfer` function for them. Sorry I'm afraid I can't marked as valid since I think this proposal would be valid but the answer doesn't addresses if that is actually correct or not.